# How to multiply two field values in pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator

In a vector layer table there are two fields `F1` and `F2` with float type. I want to multiply these fields and insert results to new field `F3`.
In below code new field created but without any value. What is problem?

```
layer = iface.activelayer()
F1 = self.ui.cBox_Width.currentText()
F2 = self.ui.cBox_Length.currentText()

new_Field = "F3"
provider = layer.dataProvider()
caps = provider.capabilities()

idx = provider.fieldNameIndex(new_Field)
try:
    if idx == -1:
        if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
            res = provider.addAttributes([QgsField(new_Field, QVariant.Double)])
except:
    return False

layer.startEditing()
bufferfield = layer.fieldNameIndex('buffer_km')
formula = QgsExpression("\"F1\" * \"F2\"")
formula.prepare(layer.pendingFields())
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = formula.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.updateFields()
layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving:

```
layer.updateFields()
```

before you start editing to ensure all newly created fields are recognised. You also need to replace:

```
f[idx] = formula.evaluate(f)
```

with something like:

```
new_Field_idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(new_Field)
f[new_Field_idx] = formula.evaluate(f)
```

as the old index would be -1 if it wasn't already created. And if you're calling your fields in your expression, you could use:

```
formula = QgsExpression(str(F1) + '*' + str(F2))
```

---

So you could try using something like the following:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
F1 = self.ui.cBox_Width.currentText()
F2 = self.ui.cBox_Length.currentText()

new_Field = "F3"
provider = layer.dataProvider()

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(new_Field)
if idx == -1:
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(new_Field, QVariant.Double)])

layer.updateFields()
layer.startEditing()
#bufferfield = layer.fieldNameIndex('buffer_km')
new_Field_idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(new_Field)
formula = QgsExpression(str(F1) + '*' + str(F2))
formula.prepare(layer.pendingFields())
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[new_Field_idx] = formula.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Hi @Joseph, Unfortunately the result field is empty.

Comment: @nickan - Apologies, edited the post :)

Comment: Sorry I can't get any result.

Comment: @nickan - Does it work if you replace `F1` and `F2` with the actual field names in the line `formula = QgsExpression(str(F1) + '*' + str(F2))`? (i.e. `formula = QgsExpression('fieldName1 * fieldName2`))

Comment: I tested your advice and replace `F1` and `F2` with field names and but it didn't work :(

Comment: I think you find problem, in Field tab of layer properties for my layer, F1 and F2 fields type is `double` and when I test the code with another field with type of `qlonglong` it works. But when I use `Field Calculator` GUI it works for `F1` and `F2` with `double` type.What is problem in this code for act on `double` type values?

Comment: @nickan - Not sure what the problem could be, I tested this on QGIS 2.18.13 and it works for me. Perhaps you can ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and see if others have similar issues?